# react select zindex not working and menutarget is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I use react select dropdown and used this to make a zindex:

```
    menuPortalTarget={document.body} 
    styles={{ menuPortal: base => ({ ...base, zIndex: 9999 }) }}
```

I also tried this

```
    menuPortalTarget={document.querySelector('.main')} 
    styles={{ menuPortal: base => ({ ...base, zIndex: 9999 }) }}
```

but if I use menuPortalTarget then I get

```
document is not defined.
```

So how can I now make my react select that zIndex works ?

Code:

```
          <Select
            name="select-station"
            className="select-station"
            placeholder="Station auswählen"
            onChange={handleChangeStation}
            isClearable
            options={station}
            styles={{ menuPortal: base => ({ ...base, zIndex: 9999999 }) }}
          />
```